# Dynamic Programming Solution for "Demerging" of two Sequences

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a problem that I am trying to solve but am having very little luck getting started. Here is the problem:

"If two sequences a1, a2,..., am and b1, b2,..., bn are interleaved, we say that the resulting sequence c1, c2,..., cm+n is a shuffle of the first two. For example,

DCCDBDADCACDBACB

is a shuffle of DCBDAACBB and CDDCDAC since it can be obtained by interleaving those two sequences in this way:

```
 DC           BDA            AC          B             B 

       CD              DC            D          AC"
```

I am to find a dynamic programming solution that figures out whether the two given subsequences are able to be merged to form the larger sequence. I have already done a problem finding the longest common subsquence and such but I can't seem to figure this one out. I know how I would go about doing it if I were to not consider dynamic programming, but I can't seem to think of how to do it with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Check this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-a-given-string-is-an-interleaving-of-two-other-given-strings-set-2/

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a DP algorithm for solving this but first creating a recursive solution for example:

```
a = 'DCBDAACBB'
b = 'CDDCDAC'
c = 'DCCDBDADCACDBACB'

an = len(a)
bn = len(b)
cn = len(c)


# recursive solution O(2^n)
def isPossible(ai, bi, ci):

    if ai == an and bi == bn and ci == cn:
        return True

    K = False

    if ci < cn and ai < an and c[ci] == a[ai]:
        K = K or isPossible(ai+1, bi, ci+1)

    if ci < cn and bi < bn and c[ci] == b[bi]:
        K = K or isPossible(ai, bi+1, ci+1)

    return K

print isPossible(0, 0, 0)
```

Here the state can be encoded as three numbers `ai, bi, ci` which indicate the index of the beginning of the suffix of the original strings and `isPossible(ai, bi, ci)` computes whether the suffixes `ai` and `bi` can be merged into the suffix `ci`, we seek `isPossible(0, 0, 0)`.

From here we can create the following DP recurrence, first initialize:

```
isPossible[ai][bi][ci] = False
isPossible[ai][bi][ci] = True where ai == an and bi == bn and ci == cn
```

Then compute:

```
isPossible[ai][bi][ci] = isPossible[ai+1][bi][ci+1] if A[ai] == C[ai]
isPossible[ai][bi][ci] = isPossible[ai][bi+1][ci+1] if B[ai] == C[ai]
```

The solution is then `isPossible[0][0][0]`. This runs in n^3, where as the recursive solution was 2^n

Comment: In the DP solution, what is ai, bi, and ci in the first initialization? Is that a 3D array?

Comment: What would the isPossible function look like in the DP solution?

Comment: The two if statements in the last part don't quite make sense as well